# How can I get the edges of low contrast image in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I'm trying to get the edges of this object from a TEM(microscope) image and the problem is that the contact is low especially in the upper edge, I tried several things thresholding, contrast equalization... but I wasn't able to get the upper edge.

**N.B:** I'm trying to calculate the angle between the droplet and the tube I'm not sure if this is the best way to approach this problem.

The original image:

[image]

The Canny Edge detection I get:

[image]

the steps I got to get this result are:

1. Contrast enhancement
2. Thresholding
3. Gauss filter
4. Canny Edge detection

Code:

```
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=clip_limit, tileGridSize=(grid_size, grid_size))
equ = clahe.apply(img)
val = filters.threshold_otsu(equ)
mask = img < val
# denoising part
mask = filters.gaussian(mask,sigma=sigmaG)
# edge detection
edge = feature.canny(mask,sigma=sigmaC)
edge = img_as_ubyte(edge)
```

Comment: You could try using [difference of gaussians](https://imgur.com/a/YUtbaUt) and then edge detect on the result.

Comment: It is a little miracle that you can get something from this horribly noisy image. You will improve by reducing the image size (blur and decimate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have this image and we want to detect the edges of the microphone:

[image]

Basically, I converted the image to grayscale, added a Gaussian blur, and detected the edges using the canny edge detector. One more important part is to fill in the gaps in the detected edges by dilating the edges and then eroding them.

All of the above is implemented in the `process` function; the `draw_contours` function basically utilizes the `process` function, and detects the greatest contour:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (11, 11), 7)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 0, 42)
    kernel = np.ones((19, 19))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=4)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=4)
    return img_erode

def draw_contours(img):
    contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.004 * peri, True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, (255, 255, 0), 2)

img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
h, w, c = img.shape

img = cv2.resize(img, (w // 2, h // 2))
draw_contours(img)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

You can omit the drop by tweaking some values int the `process` function. For example, the values

```
def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (11, 11), 10)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 0, 38)
    kernel = np.ones((13, 13))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=3)
    img_erode = cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=4)
    return img_erode
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: how can I get the line from the contour?

Comment: @Khalil.h Right above the `cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, (255, 255, 0), 2)` line, add `approx = approx[approx[:, 0].argsort(0)][-2:]` to only use the two coordinates with the greatest `x` values.

Comment: This is really helpful !